# Fetching key from GroupCache peer results in remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: go, ssl

I'm using [GroupCache](https://github.com/mailgun/groupcache) in a two peer setup on localhost. Here's how I initialize GroupCache on each peer:

```
groupCachePool := groupcache.NewHTTPPool("https://localhost:1111") // Other peer uses another port
groupCacheGroup := groupcache.NewGroup("test", 100000, &structThatImplementsGet)

server := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "localhost:1111", // Other peer uses another port
    Handler: groupCachePool,
    TLSConfig: &tls2.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    },
}

if err := server.ListenAndServeTLS("/path/to/certfile", "/path/to/keyfile"); err != nil {
    logger.Fatal("Error serving HTTPs GroupCache server", zap.Error(err))
}
```

The above does not return any error. When peer A attempts to fetch a key from peer B (this is done in the context of the `groupcache.Get()` API), I get this error on peer B:

```
http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:56364: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

This results in peer A generating the key value by itself.

I don't have a problem fetching certs from peers when the connection is not over TLS.

Here's how I generate the certificate and private key:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -subj "/C=XX/ST=StateName/L=CityName/O=CompanyName/OU=CompanySectionName/CN=localhost"
```

Both peers share the same certificate and private key.